# Switch with random not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

This is my current jScript code:

(modified STILL doesn't work)

```
function changeBG(){
    document.getElementById('imgbox').src = switch(eval(rand())){

                                                case 1: "img/img3.jpg"; 
                                                        break;
                                                case 2: "img/img2.jpg"; 
                                                        break;
                                                case 3: "img/img3.jpg"; 
                                                        break;
                                                case 4: "img/img4.jpg"; 
                                                        break; 
                                                case 5: "img/img5.jpg"; 
                                                        break; 
                                                default: "img/background.jpg"; 
                                                        break;
                                                }

}

function rand(){
    return (Math.ceil((Math.random()*10)/2));
}
```

my HTML:

```
<input id="BGchange" type="button" onclick="changeBG()" value=">"/>
```

If I do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('imgbox').src = "img/img1.jpg";
```

It just works: I click on my button, the image changes, no problem. Fact is I want the image to change to a random one between 5 each time the button is clicked; to do this I wanted to use a switch that works with a random choice inside it.

What is wrong with my coding?! :(  (I cant use jQuery or anything, just pure javascript, html and css, thats what the professor said at least)

Thank you <3

Comment: your `rand()` function doesn't return a string...

Comment: Actually I changed the code already (If you mean the "1" etc.. in the switch, cause yeah, im expecting numbers to be returned but since it didnt work already I just tried random stuff..) Anyway, I took off the "" and now it switches on numbers. Still doesnt work, same code, no "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

The switch-statement "executes" your Strings ("img/imgX.jpg") instead of returning them, so you may want put the switch in a function and then do

```
case 1: return "img/img3.jpg";
...
```

and keep in mind that each case of a switch statement must be terminated with break, otherwise the following `case`-Blocks will be executed as well!

Comment: Perfect solution, you're the best. Kudos and love.

Answer (score 0):

Your function return an integer, while your switch case is looking for a string.
Remove quotes from the switch cases and everything should work.

```
function changeBG(){
document.getElementById('imgbox').src = switch(rand()){

    case 1: "img/img3.jpg"; 
    break;
    case 2: "img/img2.jpg";
    break;
    case 3: "img/img3.jpg";
    break;
    case 4: "img/img4.jpg"; 
    break;
    case 5: "img/img5.jpg"; 
    break;
    default: "img/background.jpg";
    }

}
```

Comment: Did it a while ago, I just put those quotes for the sake of trying everything lol. Still, even when doing a switch with numbers it doesnt work at all.

Comment: You also miss break after each case statement.